# Updating a deprecated package pd.ewm_mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, deprecated

How can I update this code

Code

```
def Exponential_Moving_Average(df, n):  
    EMA = pd.Series(pd.ewma(df['Close'], span = n, min_periods = n - 1).mean(), name = 'EMA_' + str(n))  
    return df.join(EMA)
```

Error Message

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: 
>   FutureWarning: pd.ewm_mean is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a 
>   future version, replace with 
>   Series.ewm(span=10,min_periods=9,adjust=True,ignore_na=False).mean()

I tried to update it myself but I got it wrong.

EDIT: to put the updated answer would it be like this?

```
def Exponential_Moving_Average(df, n): 
EMA=df['Close'].ewm(span=n,min_periods=n-1).mean(), name = 'EMA_' + str(n)
return df.join(EMA)
```

EDIT 2: I tired the above edit and it doesn't work.  I get this message

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 3):

As they say use Series.ewm, Here `series` is referring to the column in your actual dataframe

```
EMA = df['Close'].ewm(span=n,min_periods=n-1).mean().rename('EMA_' + str(n))
```

Comment: @OptimusPrime whatever you are doing there that isn't the way of doing it. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @OptimusPrime - I try edit answer, what do you think?

Comment: @jezrael thank you for the edit :) maybe thats what Op wanted.

Comment: @Bharath I am trying to create a new column that shows the exponential moving average in the function I created

Comment: @jezrael thanks for the help, but I am trying to create a new column from the defined function.  How can you do this?

Comment: Hard to guess what you want without seeing sample data

Comment: @OptimusPrime - I guess your solution should working. Can you explain what is problem?

Comment: Cannot return function to call.  I changed it to    "return EMA" and it works